# PlantUML, Rearrangement of columns

Tags: plantuml

the following code gives me an arrangement of

**[Client | Server | Cloud]**

I want to alter the arrangement to

**[Server | Cloud | Client]**

How can I re-arrange the columns of the state-diagram?

```
@startuml
participant Client as "This is a Client"
participant Server as "This is a Server"
participant Cloud as "The big data Cloud"

Client -> Server : Request a\nHTML Document
Server -> Cloud : Get\nIngredients of content
Cloud -> Server : Deliver the\nXML content
Server -> Client : Send the \nHTML page
@enduml
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

How about placing the participants in another order:

```
@startuml
participant Server as "This is a Server"
participant Cloud as "The big data Cloud"
participant Client as "This is a Client"

Client -> Server : Request a\nHTML Document
Server -> Cloud : Get\nIngredients of content
Cloud -> Server : Deliver the\nXML content
Server -> Client : Send the \nHTML page
@enduml
```

See results at the plantuml webserver: http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/NP312i8m38RlVOgmko-mWmmSgA0NtS73BdMDMs5hPvlw_AOimYOKKlv--H9QHTA1qZIgcQljxAmTmHt31mFe24Kps0Xyj8J51ZoCFXdX49ws1wD9B_4_QP7BHYbXePIyxlQ_qINSy9qmSaVhJitr0hNlqiIGMWXcPNe9HwJMdLqVq6HD1F-2pZlAzCAinJMEDjzemDOzs2peIYphbDpaJ0P1bfXrZwhYa7_i2m00

Comment: Good, rearranging the participants works. Didn't expect that convenience!